# What does the Python function keyword do?

Tags: python

I was looking at [this line of code](https://github.com/metaperl/webelements/blob/master/WebElements/Base.py#L61) -

```
    result = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

And I was not able to find a definition of the `function` keyword for Python. Could someone link me to the docs and/or explain that this line of code does? I intuitively think I know, but I don't understand why I can't find any docs on it.

In searching through http://docs.python.org both [the `new` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/new.html?highlight=function#new.function) and its successor [types](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/types.html#module-types) seem to have something to do with it.

Comment: `function` is not a keyword in Python.

Comment: in your example `function` is an argument of the parent method, see https://github.com/metaperl/webelements/blob/master/WebElements/Base.py#L56

Comment: Seems more like an example of how you would use a function than an actual function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `function` is not a python keyword.

If you expand your view just a little, you can see that `function` is a variable (passed in as a parameter).

```
def autoAddScript(function):
    """
        Returns a decorator function that will automatically add it's result to the element's script container.
    """
    def autoAdd(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(result, ClientSide.Script):
            self(result)
            return result
        else:
            return ClientSide.Script(ClientSide.var(result))
    return autoAdd
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case `function` is just a formal parameter to the `autoAddScript` function. It is a local variable expected to have a type that allows you to call it like a function.

Answer (score 3):

function is just a variable which happen to be a function
maybe with a short example it would be clearer:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def run(function):
    print(function(3,4))

>>> run(add)
7
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all `function` is first class object in python, which means you can bind to another name like `fun = func()` or you can pass a function to another function as an argument.

So, lets start with a small snippet :

```
# I ve a function to upper case argument : arg
def foo(arg):
    return arg.upper()

# another function which received argument as function, 
# and return another function.
# func is same as function in your case, which is just a argument name.

def outer_function(func):
    def inside_function(some_argument):
        return func(some_argument)
    return inside_function

test_string = 'Tim_cook'

# calling the outer_function with argument `foo` i.e function to upper case string,
# which will return the inner_function.

var = outer_function(foo)
print var  # output is : <function inside_function at 0x102320a28>

# lets see where the return function stores inside var. It is store inside 
# a function attribute called func_closure.

print var.func_closure[0].cell_contents # output: <function foo at 0x1047cecf8>

# call var with string test_string
print var(test_string) # output is : TIM_COOK
```